# JSP Page Forward Output Includes content from previous form

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

The problem is: I have a page1.jsp which is submitted and forwarded to page2.jsp. The problem is that the forwarded output should be only the content in page2.jsp, instead of that is showing me content from page1.jsp and immediately the content from page2.jsp

I'm using `requestDispatcher.forward(String)` but i don know why is this happening

PS: I'm using JE 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems you have got the method signature incorrect . As per the [javaee 1.4 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/):

```
public void forward(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)
         throws ServletException,
                java.io.IOException
```

Hence your code should be :

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp);
dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Better , you can use the `<jsp:forward>` standard action.

> The JSP that contains the  action stops processing, clears its buffer, and forwards the request to the target resource. Note that the calling JSP should not write anything to the response prior to the  action.

**Suggested Reading:**

[How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)